# Is it possible to define our own comparator class for using order by in pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I want to order the tuples using my own comparator class.
If I run a query like say " B = ORDER A by $0,$1 "
Then the ordering should be done based on my comparator.
Please reply...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This used to be possible, but was taken out due to the fact that a) no one used it and b) it added a lot of unnecessary complexity to the code.

If you have a compelling use case, please shoot an email to the Pig user list.